# Ffmpeg stream stops after a couple of seconds

Tags: windows, http, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have an http stream of an mkv file that I am trying to transcode to mp4 via ffmpeg. Here is the command I enter to start the stream `ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -f mpeg1video -vf "scale=640:480" -r 20 "http://localhost:port"`. The stream starts fine. Here is what the stream gives me at first:`Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 31632108
      DURATION-eng    : 02:03:42.289875000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 177957
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 29347831113
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001011
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.2 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-18 22:53:22
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
      encoder         : Lavc58.31.102 mpeg1video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  111 fps=0.0 q=6.2 size=     212kB time=00:00:04.54 bitrate= 382.2kbits/s speed=8.82x` 
but after this shows up it hangs for a while then it gives me this:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown errorime=00:00:05.24 bitrate= 788.3kbits/s speed=10.5x
Error writing trailer of http://192.168.1.19:4012: Error number -10054 occurred
frame=  128 fps=1.1 q=12.1 Lsize=     646kB time=00:00:05.84 bitrate= 905.0kbits/s speed=0.0487x
video:343kB audio:274kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.639489%
[http @ 000001cb1fdac780] URL read error:  -10054
Conversion failed!
```

Here is my http server in node.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const port = port
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
var http = require('http')

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'});
})

server.listen(port, 'ipAddress')
console.log(`Example app on port ${port}!`);
```

Comment: What do the server logs say?

Comment: I cannot get the logs on windows.

Comment: I think the most likely cause is the server/server application having an upload file size cap. So your going to have to get access to it somehow

Comment: Would there still be a cap if i am streaming the file and not uploading it? Whats odd is everything works when I switch from mpeg1video to mpegts and http to udp. I also updated the question with my http server code.

Comment: "streaming the file and not uploading it" That is an artificial distinction. streaming is uploading.

Comment: Ah I see. Alright I will dive into the file size cap and see whats going on.

Comment: Could it be that I am not segmenting the file to stream it with http?